# What this mean <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms" /> in Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio 1.0.2 in which I have below build.gradle.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Android Studio gives me an error if I don't write this in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms" />
```

Earlier before latest version of Android Studio. I have to write this

```
<uses-sdk tools:node="replace" />
```

What exactly this `<uses-sdk tools:node="replace" />` and `<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms" />`.

Comment: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger

> tools:overrideLibrary marker
>
> A special marker that can only be used with uses-sdk declaration to override importing a library which minimum SDK version is more recent than that application's minimum SDK version.
> Without such a marker, the manifest merger will fail. The marker will allow users to select which libraries can be imported ignoring the minimum SDK version.

and according to http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/297xli/howto_use_the_v21_support_libs_on_older_ve

> Version 0.11 of the Android Gradle Plugin turned on a new Manifest Merger by default, and it allows us to do some nifty stuff (read more about it here). In the manifest above, I'd included a uses-sdk node that simply specifies a tools:node attribute. This specific configuration tells the manifest processor to replace any attributes from uses-sdk nodes in lower-priority manifests (such as library manifests) with the attributes in the uses-sdk node with the tools:node="replace" attribute. Since Gradle also inserts minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion from your build.gradle into this uses-sdk node, that's all we really need to add.
> Now you should be able to run your application on any device supported by your minSdkVersion, while taking advantage of the neat new views and utilities in the support lib!